# Magento 1.9.x: How to add an extra fee to order while adding item to cart programmatically?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am adding item programmatically into cart (code below) and want to add an extra fee to order. I found a lot of results here also but unable to follow as I am new in magento. Can anyone please share where to create file (observer, config.xml etc with path) and what should be the name of the file? Below code is adding item to cart successfully but I am unable to add fee to complete order.

Any help will be really appreciable.

Thanks in advance.
My code is:

```
$productId = 13114;
$price_extra = 50.00;
$product_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$_product->setMinimalPrice($price_extra);

$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$params = array(
    'product' => $productId,
    'related_product' => null,
    'qty' => 1,
    'options' => array(
        2 => array('7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'),
        1 => array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'),
    )
);
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$storeId = $customer->getStoreId();

$cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```